# Directly edit database existing in SD card

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to edit an existing .db file in SD card directly. According to [this](http://icetea09.com/blog/2014/01/22/android-use-existing-sqlite-database-in-android-app/), using the following code, it is possible to copy that database to `/data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/databases/` and then edit it, but I want to edit it in the SD card itself.

```
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
myDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: so what happens if you call `myDB.query` / `myDB.insert` / `myDB.delete` etc?

Comment: problem is before that.... using `SQLiteOpenHelper` , i don't know how to prevent to create myDB in `/data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/databases` and open existing .db file and edit it... i mean how to determine the path of existing .db file instead of define a new .db file and edit it ....

Comment: what `SQLiteOpenHelper`? you are using `SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase`, not `SQLiteOpenHelper`

Comment: i thought that for any work with databases in android i should use `SQLiteOpenHelper` ... u mean without creating an implemented class of `SQLiteOpenHelper` and using `SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase` i can edit the .db file??

Comment: sure, it returns `SQLiteDatabase`

Comment: thanks... so why in [this](http://icetea09.com/blog/2014/01/22/android-use-existing-sqlite-database-in-android-app/) tutorial , he created a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper`???

Comment: because it is a `A helper class to manage database creation and version management.` you can use it or not, depending on your needs

Comment: thanks :)... i'm new in android...

Comment: @hamed, Why not to copy the file in your app's data folder, make changes, and move back to the original location? It will have the same effect.

Comment: @MangeshGhotage yes, maybe... my mistake was using `SQLiteOpenHelper` but no need to it... using `openDatabase` simply i could edit my .db file....no my new problem is : is it possible to edit .db my own .db file existing in `/data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/databases/` without using `SQLiteOpenHelper` and simply using `openDatabase` method???!!

Comment: @hamed New post for the new problem! If your this problem is solved then mark the appropriate answer as *accepted* (or post your own answer and accept it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to friends ... this is the answer :

first u should define the database file like this :

```
SQLiteDatabase myDB;
```

then, for example for inserting :

```
myDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/sdcard/mydb.db", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

        ContentValues cv1 = new ContentValues();
        cv1.put("Field1", "new Field");
        cv1.put("Field2", "other Field");
        myDB.insert("TABLE_NAME", null, cv1);
```

or for update use this :

```
           myDB.update("TABLE_NAME", cv1, "_id=" + 1, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

With this, you can read/write to your app's internal storage... be that a DB file or not.

OR.... you CAN open/read the data from the internal DB, and then systematically copy it over into a new DB on the external storage.

This is tedious, but it gives you the opportunity to 'scrub' your DB of any 'private' info that you might not want to share.

and "tedious" isn't "quite" true, you just need to create each table again, then read each table and insert that data into the new DB.

Comment: why cannot you copy a file from for example `/sdcard/mydb.db` to `/data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/databases/mydb.db` ?

Comment: You know what... I'm sorry, I was thinking reading 'another' app's internal storage... (which requires rooting your device... ) edit above

Comment: thanks... but not my problem...i want to directly edit existing database in SDCard .... using methods like insert() , update() , delete() .... i tried that sample, it can create a database file in `/data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/databases` but not able to copy data to it...

Comment: @mawalker if i have root access, can i **edit** another app's database??

Comment: you should be able to, just check that you have a proper DBAdapter that matches the SQLfile for internal use, THEN you should be able to adjust it to work with external files fairly easily (by passing in the storage location as a parameter) (Yes, with "root" access you are "system admin" of the phone, and can edit any file you want. (even if it is a bad idea)

Comment: @mawalker thanks... i tried to edit a .db file in `/data/data/MY_PACKAGE_NAME/databases/` using **andy-roid** emulator....but my app got this : `Unfortunately, application has stopped`... i tried with `SQLite editor` app , it can't change database as well.... my emulator is rooted and my app and also `SQLite editor` both have root access... so why it's not possible to edit database in `/data/data/...` ??

Comment: @mawalker ... plz see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630155/android-edit-my-database-without-using-sqliteopenhelper)  how can i chat with u ???